# Is there a way to rotate a matplotlib plot by 45 degrees?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for a way to rotate a plot generated in matplotlib-pyplot (Python libraries) by 45 degrees (so that instead of a square shape you would have a diamond shape, for example), anyone know if this can be done?

One way I can think of is to use a rotation filter on all the data so that it appears rotated, but then the plot itself will still be in the original orientation.

I want to be able to use the matplotlib interactive features, so saving as an image and then rotating won't work.

Also, I want to use pyplot functions to draw the plot, so using a different library for the plotting is not an ideal solution.

Comment: can I ask why?  If is for something external, you might be able to get away with saving the figure as a png and then using imagemagik or related program to rotate the saved image.

Comment: @tcaswell that is possible, but I would prefer not to save to a figure since I want to use the matplotlib display features (panning, zooming, cursor/data coordination, etc.) interactively. And of course an in-library solution would be much more convenient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so currently the only partial solution I found is to apply a rotation to the plot. This allows to use the interactive interface that matplotlib/pyplot offers.

For dot plots like plot() and scatter() this is trivial, but I was specifically interested in rotating imshow(). [This](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/2009-03/msg00167.html) link discusses the *transform* keyword that could have potentially been used for this task, but it is apparently not working.

Fortunately, I found a workaround using pcolormesh(). pcolormesh() plots a quadrilateral mesh and allows you to specify the corner coordinates. So, the answer is to just apply the relevant transformations to the corner coordinates. Note however, that pcolormesh() works a bit different than imshow - it plots your matrix flipped.

I haven't seen this solution anywhere on the web, so here is some code for pcolormesh()/imshow() rotated by 45 degrees:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def pcolormesh_45deg(C):

    n = C.shape[0]
    # create rotation/scaling matrix
    t = np.array([[1,0.5],[-1,0.5]])
    # create coordinate matrix and transform it
    A = np.dot(np.array([(i[1],i[0]) for i in itertools.product(range(n,-1,-1),range(0,n+1,1))]),t)
    # plot
    plt.pcolormesh(A[:,1].reshape(n+1,n+1),A[:,0].reshape(n+1,n+1),np.flipud(C))
```

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but it was extremely useful to me. The only question I have is how to make coordinates be at the ends of the bins and not their centers?

Comment: `C` is a symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Bitwise anwer, you can use the following function:

```
def pcolormesh_45deg(C, ax=None, xticks=None, xticklabels=None, yticks=None,
                     yticklabels=None, aspect='equal', rotation=45,
                     *args, **kwargs):
    import itertools

    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    n = C.shape[0]
    # create rotation/scaling matrix
    t = np.array([[1, .5], [-1, .5]])
    # create coordinate matrix and transform it
    product = itertools.product(range(n, -1, -1), range(0, n + 1, 1))
    A = np.dot(np.array([(ii[1], ii[0]) for ii in product]), t)
    # plot
    ax.pcolormesh((2 * A[:, 1].reshape(n + 1, n + 1) - n),
                  A[:, 0].reshape(n + 1, n + 1),
                  np.flipud(C), *args, **kwargs)

    xticks = np.linspace(0, n - 1, n, dtype=int) if xticks is None else xticks
    yticks = np.linspace(0, n - 1, n, dtype=int) if yticks is None else yticks

    if xticks is not None:
        xticklabels = xticks if xticklabels is None else xticklabels
        for tick, label, in zip(xticks, xticklabels):
            ax.scatter(-n + tick + .5, tick + .5, marker='x', color='k')
            ax.text(-n + tick + .5, tick + .5, label,
                    horizontalalignment='right', rotation=-rotation)
    if yticks is not None:
        yticklabels = yticks if yticklabels is None else yticklabels
        for tick, label, in zip(yticks, yticklabels):
            ax.scatter(tick + .5, n - tick - .5, marker='x', color='k')
            ax.text(tick + .5, n - tick - .5, label,
                    horizontalalignment='left', rotation=rotation)

    if aspect:
        ax.set_aspect(aspect)
    ax.set_xlim(-n, n)
    ax.set_ylim(-n, n)
    ax.plot([-n, 0, n, 0., -n], [0, n, 0, -n, 0], color='k')
    ax.axis('off')
    return ax
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you do it on a 3D plot?

http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/How-to-rotate-a-3D-plot-td19185.html

`axes3d.view_init(elev, azim)`

Comment: That is possible, although then I have to use mplot3d's plotting functions - hopefully they will have the same capabilities that pyplot functions have. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at mplot3d, I see that it is much more limited in its 2d plotting than pyplot. So I prefer a solution that manipulates my plot made by pyplot.

Comment: Just curious...  why does it need to be rotated?  I feel like there's some data visualization technique here for me to learn.  :]

Comment: altendky - I have a dataset which gives a value for every pair of positions on some vector. This is visualized as a symmetric matrix (or a triangular matrix), and the most natural way to orient this matrix would be rotated by 45 degrees, so that the diagonal is horizontal. It is a common way to display this type of data.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.matplotlib.general/3141) post suggests that you can only do it "by hand".

> It's possible to draw it, but you would have to do all the
>   transformations/rotations by hand, including drawing the axes as
>   Line2D instances and labels as Text instances (see for example the
>   "Scatter3D" example in the archives).  There is no easy, built-in, way
>   to do it, currently.  In the planned refactoring of the axis handling,

Comment: Thanks, although that post is from 2005 so there is a chance that in the 7+ years since then there have been changes...

Comment: @ i agree, I hope you find something, i would be happy to be wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)?

This code will rotate an image. So if you first output the plot to a file as an image, you could then do

```
import Image
img = Image.open("plot.jpg")
img2 = img.rotate(45)
img2.show()
img2.save("rotate.jpg")
```

Comment: This works if you don't care about axis rotated (or if you don't have them to worry about)

Comment: See my answer above to tcaswell, I want the interactive features in matplotlib, so this is less useful.