# Rotate an image in matplotlib?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I want to rotate an image generated by `plt.imshow()`. Is that possible somehow? I don't want to rotate (with `scipy.ndimage.rotate` for example) the underlying array I use for plotting, because it always introduces artifacts, and they are affecting what I'm looking at in the image. Also would be better for me to have pixels rotated by 45 degrees.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23790983/1304161), where it's suggested to use use the scipy rotate method on the figure. But it doesn't work for me. This is the relevant code:

```
im = plt.imshow(np.log2(data+1), origin='lower', interpolation='none', cmap=WhRd,
                        extent=[0, (end-start)*200000, 0, 50*200000])
im_rot = ndimage.rotate(im, 45)
```

And this is the error, pointing at the second line:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/ndimage/interpolation.pyc in rotate(input, angle, axes, reshape, output, order, mode, cval, prefilter)
    631         axes[1] += rank
    632     if axes[0] < 0 or axes[1] < 0 or axes[0] > rank or axes[1] > rank:
--> 633         raise RuntimeError('invalid rotation plane specified')
    634     if axes[0] > axes[1]:
    635         axes = axes[1], axes[0]

RuntimeError: invalid rotation plane specified
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

- Maybe using [ndimage.rotate with interpolation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html#scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate) would reduce the artifacts in your plot? You can select the interpolation method which fits you requirements.
- Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848581/is-there-a-way-to-rotate-a-matplotlib-plot-by-45-degrees) might be of help - it doesn't use ndimage.

Comment: Thank you! I want to avoid interpolation completely, but the second idea might work!

Comment: OK, so I made it work, and it's great, but there is one serious issue: in my real data the pixels are not square. Consider this: http://itmages.ru/image/view/2758693/d2e77924 This is reproducible with any data when saving the image with plt.savefig, but is not visible in the interactive matplotlib window. Is there any way to have square pixels? Boosting dpi helps of course, but the image size grows quite fast then...